# Why is conversion not working?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, integer, radix

I'd like to develop an algorithm that is able to do a **AnyBase 2 AnyBase conversion** in C++.

So I started with just translating [this javascript code](https://gist.github.com/ryansmith94/91d7fd30710264affeb9) into C++ and ended with the use of a [BigInt - library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/) because it will of course not work using integer (long int, long double, etc) precision - so I had to use the BigInt library.

This is the code I came up with. Till now I'm not getting error-messages or warnings but the conversion doesn't seems to do it's job right:

```
string enc1 = convertBaseBigInt("A", 64, 4);
cout << "enc1: " << enc1 << endl;               // gets "210000"

string dec1 = convertBaseBigInt(enc1, 4, 64);   // gets "2g0" (instead of "A")
cout << "dec1: " << dec1 << endl;
```

---

Please have a look at my code:

```
std::string convertBase(string value, int from_base, int to_base) {
string range = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+/";
string  from_range = range.substr(0, from_base),
        to_range = range.substr(0, to_base);

int dec_value = 0;
int index = 0;
string reversed(value.rbegin(), value.rend());
for(std::string::iterator it = reversed.begin(); it != reversed.end(); ++it) {
    index++;
    char digit = *it;
    if (!range.find(digit)) return "error";
    dec_value += from_range.find(digit) * pow(from_base, index);
}
string new_value = "";
while (dec_value > 0) {
    new_value = to_range[dec_value % to_base] + new_value;
    dec_value = (dec_value - (dec_value % to_base)) / to_base;
}
return new_value;
}
```

I hope somebody is able to help me to find my error because it seems like I can not find it on myself.

Thanks a million in advance, Tempi.

Comment: Why are you calling the `operator` functions rather than using the operators?

Comment: For instance, `BigInt::Rossi newDec = (decValue - decValue % base) / base;` is far more readable than your sequence of function calls and string conversions. If you don't complicate things so much it's much easier to find bugs.

Comment: @molbdnilo Good point, yes. Still, that does not seem to change the "not-working" of the code. Too bad.

Comment: So the code `(C++)` is my translation from the javascript code you can [find right](https://gist.github.com/ryansmith94/91d7fd30710264affeb9) here. I've improved the javascript-code by using bigInt instead of just Int with 53bit precision (as javascript does). Hope I could answer your comment :) @Teemu

Comment: JS is still totally irrelevant to the question ... No matter how many JS lines I'd wrote as an answer, it wouldn't help you to solve the C++ problem at hands.

Comment: Oh, it's all about the wrong `js-tag` @Teemu? Ok sure - I understood. **Edited** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you do not use the right 'index' value, it should start on 0 not 1

Remove

```
index++
```

And modify the line

```
BigInt::Rossi add(to_string((int)(from_range.find(digit) 
 * pow(from_base, index))), BigInt::DEC_DIGIT);
```

to

```
BigInt::Rossi add(to_string((int)(from_range.find(digit) 
 * pow(from_base, index++))), BigInt::DEC_DIGIT);
```

I would also recommend dropping the operator keyword

e.g.

```
decValue.operator>(BigInt::Rossi("0", BigInt::DEC_DIGIT))
```

when this is clearer

```
decValue > BigInt::Rossi("0", BigInt::DEC_DIGIT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. You're right - my mistake of course the index++ should be triggered afterwards. However - the algorithm doesn't seems to work anyway. Please have a look at my edit :)

Comment: Edit: You get the "right-answer" checkmark even if my question is not solved yet. Maybe you like to see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629359/why-is-the-conversion-not-working

Comment: I think you should drop the BigInt library and try to get it running with long int first, then once the algorithm is working, add back BigInt. If I were you I would also try and simplify the code a bit, there is a lot of string int conversion which makes the code difficult to read. You could at least do some helper functions for that.

Comment: The algorithm is already working with int. This is my first approach using long int, long double, etc  - but with these types only small strings can be encoded because otherwise it comes to issues. SO I switched to a bigInt library.

Comment: @tempi yes you seem to be right, maybe there the problem is in bigint or the handling of bigint?

Comment: I'm not sure - could be YES but I don't know how to handle this.